# asp.net and jquery ui draggable beginners

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi im very new to jquery and combining it into my asp.net work stuffs.

Ive read the order you reg the jquery files matters, so ive put the core file at the top ?
I really dont understand what im getting wrong here :

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ph">
       <script src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript">     </script>
       <script src="development-bundle/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript">     </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

  $(function () {

     $("#draggable").draggable();

  });

 </script> 
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnl_deck_holder" runat="server">

    </asp:Panel>
 <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    drag me
    </div>


 </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

jquery-1.7.2 should be first, followed by jquery.ui.core and other UI components. But, if you're using the jquery UI, it usually bundles everything you need in one file if you use the download builder.

Comment: the download builder gave me a zip file containing a js folder with jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js and jquery-1.7.2.min.js
and a 'development-bundle' folder with all the files i picked for the download
do i only need the first 2 files inside the js ?
and i assume (if so)  they go in the e order of jquery-1.7.2 then jquery-ui ?

Comment: Yes, jQuery first, then the ui .js files. The other stuff (css and images) are for the theme you chose. If you want that theme, they need to be in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this . first Jquery Source file, then the Jquery UI .

```
<script src="development-bundle/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript">
```